# Files.readAllLines prepending unprintable characters

Tags: java, file

I am reading a large JSON file into a string using java (OpenJDK 8).

The code I am using is `final String fileContents = (Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath.toString()))).stream().collect(Collectors.joining());`

The resulting String has some unprintable characters at the start of the string which aren't in the file:

[image]

Eclipse shows the characters as [-1,-2] before the `{"TIPL` etc. which is the actual file.

What is wrong here? What can I do to get Java to read the file correctly?

Comment: It's prolly BOM... FF FE means that it's utf16le

Comment: Yes, thank you, Notepad++ confirms it thinks there's a BOM there. How can I get java to parse the file correcly?

Comment: Are you sure that your file is UTF-8 encoded? If not, you need to pass the correct charset to `readAllLines()`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Notepad++ seems to think it's "UTF8-BOM" (I get the file from an online source, so have no control over what comes)

Comment: I second @Selvin. Looks like UTF-16. It has the UTF-16LE BOM, and every other char in your screenshot is a NUL byte.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `.replaceFirst("\u00EF\u00BB\u00BF", "").replaceFirst("\ufeff", "")` to the end of the read works, but feels clunky. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is encoded as UTF16-LE (little-endian) and contains a [byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (`FF FE`).

The default encoding used by `Files.readAllLines()` is UTF-8, so that's why you're seeing the byte-order mark (BOM) characters and NUL characters in your string data.

You should pass a character set as your second parameter to [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-):

```
Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

The `StandardCharsets.UTF_16` encoding will automatically interpret the BOM, and parse your string content accordingly. The Javadoc for the [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class contains additional information on how byte-order marks are encoded and decoded using various character encodings.

Comment: @tucuxi This is not about the default character set. Check the linked [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-): *"Read all lines from a file. Bytes from the file are decoded into characters using the UTF-8 charset."*